# I have a problem whith HTML and CSS div height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website where I occurred this error. Where I am trying to position an `h1` element,
but there is something coming between my way. Here [This is the image the blue part is highlighted and coming in my way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeUpG.png). I tried using inspect but it tells its a div called (our-team).but as per my CSS the div has height as much as the background image CSS code:-.

```
.our-team{
height: 500px;
}
```

html code:-

```
  <div class="our-team">
      <img class="background-team" 
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/807598/pexels-photo-807598.jpeg? 
      auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="" srcset="">

      <h1 class="heading-team">Our Team</h1>
      <div class="team-members">
        <h1 class="member-name">Lara</h1>
      </div>
```

And when I inspect on our team it shows an image([This is the inspected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ8Ey.png)).
Thank you,

Comment: Need more context. Please add the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Put your HTML and CSS code in the question

Comment: You need to put height and width for the img element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example, you didn't close the first `div.our-team` tag
Maybe that's the reason?
BTW, if I understood you correctly, maybe this one help you?
https://jsfiddle.net/Madebyspeedster/fq0emnk1/14/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and move the margin or padding to a -25px